# Правильно ли реализовать такую логику на Redux или какие советы могут быть лучше?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть корзина товаров, добавления и хранения сделал через Redux. Есть разные action.type, добавить в корзину, удалить из корзины, добавить единицу, удалить единицу и.т.п
Так же надо было во время обновления посчитать финальную цену. Думал для каждого action.type добавить цикл map и пройтись по всем ценам, однако это работает с опозданием в 1 клик , стейт обновляется. Сделал следующий образом но мне кажется не совсем корректным, хотя работает отлично

Заметил что при любом изменений стейта у нас срабатывает componentDidUpdate и за чего добавил такой код

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    const products = this.props.cart
    let totalPrice = 0
    products.map(item =>{
      totalPrice += item.priceGroup
    })
    this.props.updatePrice(totalPrice)
  }


export function updatePrice(totalPrice){
  return{
    type: UPDATE_PRICE,
    totalPrice
  }
}

case UPDATE_PRICE:
      return {
        ...state,
        totalPrice: action.totalPrice
      }
```

Как и говорил все работает) но при Update_PRICE срабатывает еще раз componentDidUpdate т.е он работает 2 раза на каждую итерацию( сначала на изменения количество, а потом еще раз и за того что цену обновил и state обновился)
Какие могут быть более корректные решения
Структура такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите - у Вас есть вычисляемое поле (чистая функция от redux store) и Вы его вычисляете в componentDidUpdate - это как раз полбеды :)

А если totalprice надо записать в нескольких местах ? - каждый раз вычислять в каждом компоненте ?

Вторая беда - что вычислив его Вы вызываете dispatch action что естественно ведет к повторному рендеру - а в некоторых случаях может привести к бесконечному циклу :)

Как лучше сделать ?
Я бы в reducer при изменении цены/количества товара автоматом бы менял и total sum

Вариант 2 (хуже)
Мемоизируйте вычисление в компоненте и конечно не вызывайте dispatch на вычисляемое поле
https://medium.com/@mohsentaleb/how-to-effectively-memoize-methods-in-react-class-components-with-lodash-a6df0569dd5a

Comment: Согласен, поэтому хочу избежать повторного вызова функции. 
По поводу вашего совета менять в reducer. Идея отличная только у меня там 8 разных типов, поэтому надо в каждом делать просчитывания функции что не очень удобно. А делать просчет в начале до изменения state неверно, ибо тогда state обновится после еще одного изменения